# Linkedin iOS integration issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api

I am trying to sent invitation by Email id using LinkedIn API

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/mailbox"];
OAMutableURLRequest *request =
[[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                consumer:consumer
                                   token:token
                                callback:nil
                       signatureProvider:nil];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *messageToPerson = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/people/email=anuisac@gmail.com"];
NSDictionary *person = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:messageToPerson,@"_path",@"Anu",@"first-name",@"Isac",@"last-name",nil] , @"person",nil];
NSArray *valueArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:person,nil];
NSDictionary *values = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:valueArray,@"values", nil];
NSDictionary *ir = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"friend",@"connect-type",nil] , @"invitation-request",nil];
NSDictionary *ic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:ir,@"item-content", nil];
NSDictionary *update = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:values,@"recipients",@"Invitation",@"subject",@"ConnectWithMe",@"body", ir, @"item-content", nil];
[request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSLog(@"%@",[update description]);
NSString *updateString = [update JSONString];

[request prepare];

[request setHTTPBodyWithString:updateString];
```

and the response is error message as shown

```
"errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Access to sending invitation denied.",
  "requestId": "LFECWXJDXG",
  "status": 403,
  "timestamp": 1375091724948
```